# How can I stop my code running inside a method without giving the return wanted

Tags: java

I am trying to run some code that checks an input is an integer. This method is called from main and tries to convert the input to an integer number. If this fails it will print an error message and then I would like the code to stop. The method called is below:

When trying to compile this gives out an error:

missing return statement }

Any idea on how this can be done?

```
public static int checkCharactersPerLineInput(String inputNumber){
    try{
        int length = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber);
        return length;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with input... Not an integer please 
            try again.");
            System.exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: Replace int with void, or return any value as what you want.

Comment: Throw an exception. That's what they're for. And don't catch generic exceptions like that. `parseInt` throws very specific exceptions. Use that.

Comment: You know 'exit' terminates the entire program, right?  Giving up on the first typing error is pretty harsh, especially since you're telling him to 'try again'.

Answer (score 1):

Any method that is not declared void must contain a return statement with a corresponding return value, like this:

`return returnValue;`

Since your method has a return type 'int', you need to have an integer return value. If you don't want to return anything, just use void.

You might want to read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html#targetText=Within%20the%20body%20of%20the,but%20it%20may%20do%20so.).

Answer (score 0):

`public static int checkCharactersPerLineInput(String inputNumber){`

All functions and methods have to return a value (your method doesn't, so it is giving an error), unless it is a void or constructor.

Either

A) Add a `return someInteger` statement into your `checkCharactersPerLineInput` method

B) Replace `int` with `void`.

Comment: constructors do return a value.

Comment: No, I don't believe they do.

Answer (score 0):

The point of methods that return values is that they return values, thus, wherever your method is implemented, will need a proper integer.
A way to get around this might be putting `return null;` into the catch part and wherever your method is called you first need to check

```
if (checkCharactersPerLineInput(str)!=null){
    //your code
}
```

If you are just interested in the numbers of the String, you can also replace `int length = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber);` with `int length = Integer.parseInt(inputNumber.replaceAll("[^1234567890]", "");` which will remove every character in the String that's not a digit. You can then also remove the `try` and `catch` phrases from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trick of returning a null value if it fails.. But you would have to change the return type to java.lang.Integer